# Gradle window in missing in android studio for my flutter project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, flutter

The gradle window is missing in the android studio for my flutter project but it is available for my Kotlin project.

[image]

I have to generate the `signing certificate SHA-1` to register my app in Firebase.

Comment: How did you open project? Open it as a Gradle project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_import

Comment: I have created this project in the android studio itself.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how you find the gradle section in Android Studio for a Flutter-Project:

1. Open the build.gradle file in app/src/
2. There should appear a small bar at the top of the code-editor and click *Open for Editing in Android Studio*

[image: Android Studio]

3. A new window will open, showing the option for opening the gradle section in the side-panel, as expected.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091158/9248277) is giving you a quite extensive explanation for then generating the SHA1-fingerprint.

Answer (score 2):

The problem for Android Studio is that the android(gradle)-project is not top-level.
You can **right-click on project- or android-folder, select Flutter->'Open Android module in Android Studio'** .
[image]
After that the gradle-tab appears on the right and you can use it as intended.