# Generate SHA-1 for Flutter/React-Native/Android-Native app

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, dart, sha1

I'm trying to generate a SHA-1 for a Flutter app, for Android studio to support Google Sign in, but I don't know how to do that, I saw some posts that indicate to run a command, but there I need a jks file I guess, and flutter doesn't create that.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Here is my solution posted for same question
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53685876/6183464)

Comment: The Gradle Console tab has been replaced by "Build" in Android Studio 3.1, accessible from View -> Tool Windows -> Build.

Answer (score 349, accepted):

**TERMINAL**

Go to the project folder in the terminal.

Mac
`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Windows
`keytool -list -v -keystore "\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Linux
`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

**GUI Android Studio.**

1. Select android/app/build.gradle file and on the right top corner click "Open for Editing in Android Studio"

[image]

2. Open Gradle panel and double click on "SigninReport",

see [Android studio Gradle Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253196/android-studio-gradle-tab/62337288#62337288)

[image]

3. That's it! If you use Firebase - add these 2 keys there. You should add both keys, otherwise, without the release key, Google login will not work on the devices.

[image]

Comment: Is it want to add all sha key to firebase? and after added sha, is it need to replace google-service.json file?

Comment: The Only Detailed Solution that is working for my flutter project. Thank you a lot <3

Comment: I cannot see the "Open for Editing in Android Studio" option

Comment: In this case on mac you can use 
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: In my case it was "import Gradle project" for my Flutter app. But had to wait for indexing a bit.

Comment: Worked like magic, only I had a hard time figuring out on the second step opening Gradle yet it is on the right android studio by default. I hope that helps someone.

Comment: Also, you can directly open the `android`(project name -> android) as an android project

Comment: If you cannot see the "Open in Android Studio" option, close your Flutter project. In Android Studio -> Open the `android` module of the flutter project in Android Studio from its path.

Comment: The Gradle Console tab has been replaced by "Build" in Android Studio 3.1, accessible from View -> Tool Windows -> Build.

Comment: This one gives me the debug key. How can I get the release key? So that I can use it for production.

Comment: If you can't see gradle tasks in the gradle tool, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405791/gradle-tasks-are-not-showing-in-the-gradle-tool-window-in-android-studio-4-2

Comment: You nailed it. I'm linux user. Spent 4+ hours  to slove. Finally. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Dani You should add `.iml` file in Project android/ folder. Make sure the file name syntax should be <your_project_name>_android.

Comment: This is the best answer that worked for me. I was distributing the adhoc build for Android using Firebase app distribution and without adding the release SHA-1 fingerprint to Firebase, Google sign in simply wasn't working. Adding both release and debug SHA-1 fingerprints to Firebase console did the trick. Burnt a lot of time trying to figure this out, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 277):

This is the easiest way-

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Project
3. Reveal android folder
4. **Right click "gradlew" file and select  Open in Terminal -**

[image: Open in Terminal]

5. Go to the terminal view and paste: `gradlew signingReport` or `./gradlew signingReport` if you're using PowerShell or a Unix-based system like mac.

[image: Paste]

6. **Press enter and scroll to "Variant: debug" to get the SHA1 key**

[image: Scroll to key]

7. Copy and use wherever you need it, Good Luck!

Comment: it takes time for configuring process

Comment: For those of us that get an error about JAVA_HOME not being set, I updated my environment variables and added a System variable named `JAVA_HOME` set to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`. Then I updated my Path variable and added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. Then this answer worked for me.

Comment: This one give me the `debug` key. How can I get the `release` key. So that I can use it for production.

Comment: @WilliamHerrmann - I got the `JAVA_HOME` error, too, but Android Studio told me to run it using `ctrl+return` which runs it in the IDE instead of the terminal - that worked for me, too.

Comment: For ubuntu - android studio correct command or usage; right cicl to project/android/gradlew "run gradlew option>  after that in below terminal screen, press up keyword and use;  /bin/bash "your android studio folders path"/AndroidStudioProjects/project_folder/android/gradlew signingReport

Comment: This solved the API exception *PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)*

Comment: Why my key is much longer than others. I also would like to achieve auth in flutter with microsoft, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71338563/how-to-generate-package-signature-in-flutter-azure-connection-msal

Comment: Update, Now windows users will have to write same as Mac: 
./gradlew signingReport

Comment: Best for Flutter projects. Run the command ./gradlew signingReport. to get SHA Key.

Comment: for `WINDOWS` use `./gradlew signingReport` if your using `powershell`

Comment: if gradlew command doesn’t work add ./ before the command like: ./gradlew
I found the error gradlew command not found and adding ././gradlew works for me

Comment: This works for me to implement Supabase Google Auth. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 144):

You won't find a gradle window view in flutter project, so here is a solution for that.. In command prompt navigate to bin folder of jdk and run this command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\yourusernamehere\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

change user name in path

Comment: for mac command is
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: thank you rishab  the ``./gradlew signingReport`` for the life of me didn't work for me on my flutter project and even the gradle window in android studio

Answer (score 120):

I partially agree with Rishab answer, but what we can do is

and this approach works with all `flutter/React-native/Android` ....

Navigate to Android folder inside project, there is gradlew file. so we can use this like :

```
gradlew signingReport
```

in Mac

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

in my case i use it like :

```
D:\flutter\flutter_app\android>gradlew signingReport
```

*Project Architecture is :*

[image]

Comment: Easyest solution by far ! once you will have enter ./gradlew signinReport, the SH1 key will be prompted

Comment: I did the following: 
cd android 
./gradlew signingReport 

But the details of the ~/user/debug.keystore were printed. 
Shall we not use the debug.keystore inside the folder instead?? or what??

Answer (score 47):

so if you are using an android studio or VS code it's work both of them

=> Open Terminal

=> cd android

[image]

=> signingReport

[image]

and the final output like this as given in the image below choice your SSH key in at the place of here is your SSH key

[image]

in the above output, image is shown in dummy data I change some of the fields just because of security purpose

Edit: for mac

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Answer (score 39):

run this commend
it work any where

in android folder

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

for example

```
PS E:\flutterProject\flutter_app\android> ./gradlew signingReport
```

some time you not need add ./ just

> `gradlew signingReport`

this work for android studio and cmd and commond prome

Comment: the `./`isn't needed for me in Windows. This works using `gradlew signingReport`

Answer (score 18):

you can do the same on VSCode, open the folder that contain gradlew for linux and gradlew.bat for windows and run `./gradlew signingReport` for Window and run `gradlew signingReport` for Linux

[image: run ./gradlew signingReport]

Answer (score 17):

1-write those two commands in android studio's or vscode terminal:

```
cd android
gradlew signingReport
```

2-wait a bit then scroll up.

in linuix

```
cd android
./gradlew signingReport
```

Answer (score 15):

Simple and easy:

```
cd android && gradlew signinReport
```

Comment: work for me ,flutter on vscode "cd android && ./gradlew signinReport"

Answer (score 14):

For Android Studio 4.2 and Flutter 2.2

**Windows:**

**Open your project open android > gradlew > right click on it and click open in terminal**

Like below:

[image]

**My Project Directory: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\WowTalentNew\android>gradlew**

open this in terminal.

After build finished execute this

**D:\AndroidStudioProjects\YourProjectDirectory\android>gradlew signinReport**

After that you will see the SHA keys

[image]

Here's my full CMD screen

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\AndroidStudioProjects\WowTalentNew\android>gradlew

> Configure project :app
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :help

Welcome to Gradle 6.3.

To run a build, run gradlew <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradlew tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradlew --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradlew help --task <task>

For troubleshooting, visit https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 
7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\WowTalentNew\android>gradlew signinReport

> Configure project :app
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\apoor\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: 2A:97:87:DF:E1:58:D4:9D:E6:65:18:********
SHA1: 4E:0E:D0:F7:68:51:80:47:3E:D1:**************************
SHA-256: 
17:83:42:F4:0E:59:C5:5B:1E********************************************************
BC:79
Valid until: Saturday, November 26, 2050
```

in Linux instead of just type gradlew we write ./gradlew to build. and to get SHA-1 we write: Terminal> ./gradlew signinReport and we could just build and get SHA-1 key with just one command: Terminal> ./gradlew signinReport

I hope it clears everything, happy coding!

Comment: that's work, please add linux command to your answer so it'll benefit more people:

in linux instead of just type gradlew we write ./gradlew to build.
and to get SHA-1 we write:
Terminal> ./gradlew signinReport

and we could just build and get SHA-1 key with just one command:
Terminal> ./gradlew signinReport

Comment: @mohannadalnono Updated, and thanks for your input. Please check and correct me if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 12):

## To generate SHA-1 for a Flutter :

**1. Locate your android directory inside  the console**

```
E:\<appname>\android>
```

**2. After locating to the android folder  run this command**

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

---

## If this won't work and opens a daemon terminal

**1. Type  `signingReport` in  daemon terminal**

```
daemon> signingReport
```

> This would be taking a bit long time to generate your first SHA-1  as it
> would be checking for all the firebase dependencies and after that
> over it generate the SHA-1.

Comment: It works, however it generated a debug SHA. How can I generate a release SHA?

Comment: I could find a release SHA-1 by this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyJNP3-N838&ab_channel=FlutterMapp

Comment: @BehzodFaiziev Thank you for trying out my solution! If it helped you solve your problem, please consider upvoting my answer. Upvotes help to highlight useful and accurate answers, and they help me to contribute more to the Stack Overflow community. Thanks again, and I'm glad that I could help!

Answer (score 8):

Check this [Authenticating Your Client  |  Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

To get the debug certificate fingerprint:

**for Mac or Linux**

```
keytool -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

**for Windows**

```
keytool -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

The default password for the debug keystore is ***android***.

The keytool then prints the fingerprint to the terminal.

Answer (score 7):

***1. First Methord***
just run the below command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

***2. Second Methord***

**1. Left side**
open the android folder not the whole project in android studio.

**2. Right Side** open the file android/app/Tasks/anroid/signingReport

**Final** this process will take some time and it might be of 5-10 minutes so be patient

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This solution work for me in MAC os Monterey and Android studio Bumblebee

open the android folder in terminal

**right click on Android folder>Open In>Terminal**

[image]
it will open new terminal window
and run below command

```
bash ./gradlew signingreport
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate it even from terminal.  Following is for the release mode:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore_location -alias alias_name
```

example :

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /home/user/key.jks -alias alias_name
```

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**

- Make sure java is installed in your system.

[image]

**Method 2**

- Using Command-line change your username and run the below command

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\.android\debug.keystore
```

- the default password is **android**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

go to the android folder in terminal

**cd android
.\gradlew signingReport**

*it will generate your SHA1 and SHA256 for you*

Comment: ./gradlew signingReport

Answer (score 3):

If you have the keystore file, then run `keytool -list -v -keystore fileName.jks -alias upload -storepass password -keypass password` at the keystore file location...

Answer (score 2):

First, check which Keystore is being used by your project in

[image]

Then use the below command

```
 keytool -list -v -alias mstoreappsemoAlias -keystore  fluxstorepro/android/app/mstoresemoFile.keystore
```

and if you want to generate a hash key for Facebook then use the below command

```
 keytool -exportcert -alias mstoreappsemoAlias -keystore fluxstorepro/android/app/mstoresemoFile.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Answer (score 2):

**To get generate a SHA-1 key**

*in the terminal type* `cd android` *and change the path*  *then type* `./gradlew signingReport`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a Mac and Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1.

None of the answers with visual directions worked for me because when I pressed the gradle/elephant in the upper right hand corner of Android studio, there were only 2 paths MyPojectName/app. Everyone else's has more paths underneath however mines only has 2.

When I pressed the elephant (`Execute Gradle Task`) and I typed in `signingReport` nada. I looked through the list but it wasn't there.

When I opened Terminal in Android studio and entered `gradlew signingReport`  nothing found. Then I tried `./gradlew signingReport` and still nothing.

Long story short it only took 2 easy steps to find the keys. I first followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73232876/4833705):

1- `Android Studio`/`Preferences`/`Build,Execution,Deployment`/`Build Tools`/`Gradle`. In the right panel click the `Gradle JDK` dropdown then select `Download JDK`

2- After that finished, while in Android Studio I opened `Terminal`

[image]

In there I followed [R7G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72541479/4833705) (his answer didn't work at first without step 1) and entered this into terminal (bottom of Android Studio):

```
bash ./gradlew signingreport
```

And like that, both keys appeared

[image]

Another option is to add Gradle either using Homebrew

```
brew install gradle
```

or [install gradle manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72541479/4833705)

To find where gradle is [located on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45984843/4833705)

Another option is to [run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62931536/4833705) `gradle wrapper` and follow the prompts

Answer (score 1):

> Flutter Project Using MAC & VS Code

- Step One
  Go To the Android Gradle Properties and add this line

**https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip**

[image]

- Step Two
  Open the Terminal at android Folder of your Projects .
  then in the terminal type

**.\gradlew signinReport**

you will get the signing report Like this :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try writing this in Terminal - For Windows

> cd android

> gradlew signingReport

Answer (score 1):

**For Mac Users**

If after typing **./gralew signingReport** inside **android** folder gives you this error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

Then follow this process:

1. Run **flutter doctor -v**
2. Now inside the **Android toolchain** copy the location after **Java binary at:**. It will be something like this:
   `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java`
3. Paste it in the project's root location and Replace the java at the end of the above location with `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`.

You are done, you will see the keys now.

Answer (score 0):

for linux:

1. if you are using vscode you can right-click on gradlew->copypath (in my case: `/home/alif/Documents/project/flutter/fit_app/android/gradlew`)
2. open your terminal and paste it, **don't forget to delete /gradlew**
3. type `.../android gradlew signinReport` and hit enter

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to check the fingerprint in Google Play Console, since I have Google Play managed app signing.

The ones provided by gradlew did not work for me.

Note that you can put both in Firebase, but you only need one. I just added the SHA1 and Google Sign In began working.

[image: Google Play Console]

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I went to the terminal then navigated to *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin* (navigate to your java bin folder).

Next, I ran this command and it worked: *keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android*

Answer (score 0):

You can use one line in terminal

```
echo y | keytool -genkeypair -dname "cn=Chris, ou=JavaSoft, o=Sun, c=US" -alias business -keypass kpi135 -keystore /working/android.keystore -storepass ab987c -validity 20000
```

- dname is a unique identifier for the application in the .keystore
- cn the full name of the person or organization that generates the
  .keystore
- ou Organizational Unit that creates the project, its a subdivision of
  the Organization that creates it. Ex. android.google.com
- o Organization owner of the whole project. Its a higher scope than
  ou. Ex.: google.com
- c The country short code. Ex: For United States is "US"
- alias Identifier of the app as an single entity inside the .keystore
  (it can have many)
- keypass Password for protecting that specific alias.
- keystore Path where the .keystore file shall be created (the standard
  extension is actually .ks)
- storepass Password for protecting the whole .keystore content.
- validity Amout of days the app will be valid with this .keystore

Answer (score 0):

Solution for **Windows Flutter 2022-23** solution to get **SHA-1**

First solution:-

1. In your project terminal type `cd android`
2. now you're inside the android folder now type `./gradlew` then type

   gradlew signinReport

*IF you got this error then try next solution*

[image]

second solution

1. Again type `cd android` in your root project
2. Now type `./gradlew signingReport`

you will surely get SHA-1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **flutter** I hope it will work for you,

1. If you are using vs code then open terminal or if you are using other stuff then Goto the **project folder** and **open terminal** and past below code

   keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users%your user name%.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

It's work for me. i think will work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

For windows user with flutter

run the command below in your project terminal

```
cd android
```

then run this command

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

Answer (score -1):

Working solution in 2022 for all Android apps including React Native and Flutter. If you need to see SHA-1 certificate code but all other options did not work, you can try this. Suggested solutions like running commands from Command Line and other suggested ways through Android Studio was giving this error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'. No need to unistall Java, remove java files or play with system path values as mentioned by others.

Here is how you can get it work:

1. Find Gradle window on the right panel, inside Android Studio and click on famous Gradle icon
   [image]

[image]

3. Type "gradle signingReport" and wait the process finish. It will print out all SHA-1, SHA-256, MD5 etc for you.
   [image]

Note: If you see this error `Task 'signing' is ambiguous in root project... Candidates are...` you need to clean the project(Top level menu `Build` --> `Clean Project`) first and then run this `gradle signingReport` again.

Answer (score -1):

**Easy Solution**

*for windows*

1. cd to android
2. ./gradlew