# Flutter App showing blank screen after downloding from play store, although i have used the SHA-1

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

The first release it was working fine, because i was not using firestore. but the second update i have used cloud firestore only, i didnt use firebase auth. and updated the app. now i can download the app but can't use it. There is a SHA-1 in play store which i integerated with my firestore, but still not able to use. Is there anything that i am missing.

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630123/flutter-generate-release-sha1-fingerprint) but didn't solve my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter build apk --no-shrink`. It might help.

Here is the discussion: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70558