# Gradle is missing from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm new to the android studio I see Gradle is not showing in my Android studio, how I can install or display the Gradle option in the right toolbar, any advice would be highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clone of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253196/android-studio-gradle-tab Look at the second answer.

Comment: It looks like you've opened the root project of whatever you've checked out - have you tried opening the `android` directory as a project instead?

Comment: I have opened the android directory still no gradle tab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253196/android-studio-gradle-tab

I checked all answers on this post and tried still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is

I have opened a new project and only the `android` folder as a project (from inside my project)