# How do I generate SHA-1 for Flutter app from Linux command line

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to generate an SHA-1 for the android debug build of Flutter app so that I can use Firebase Authentication methods which require that (e.g. phone authentication dynamic links).

I have seen a number of solutions suggesting using the Gradle window in Android Studio, but this is not applicable for a Flutter project.

I understand I can do this from the command line using the java `keytool` utility.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53685909/10797095) is available for the Windows command line but I am using *nix (Debian Linux on a Chromebook).

Also, I do not have the full Java JDK installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `gradlew signingReport` from the `android` directory under the root of your flutter project:

```
myflutterproject/android$ ./gradlew signingReport
```

This assumes you have JAVA_HOME and PATH to bin directory set.

If you do not have the full JDK installed, the location of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) embedded with Android Studio can be found by running:

`$ flutter doctor -v`

With a default Android Studio installation the location of the JRE should be:

`/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/`

To set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and PATH to the bin directory, add the following lines to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/android-studio/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

(Close and reopen the terminal window before use)

Answer (score 1):

First create a flutter project and open in android studio.

Then select **android package**.

In android package, select **gradlew** file. Right click on it and select option **"open in terminal"**

Then in terminal command line, add the command below

```
gradlew signingReport
```

Then It will list SHA1 & SHA256 and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I find Android studio heavy going for my 4MB system, so prefer the pure command line solution!