# Flutter Firebase authentication only work when you give test phone number

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

My code is working but it authenticate only the test phone no, which is given in the Firebase authentication.

when I'm trying with other number is directly going to **PhoneVerificationFailed()** and this is the exception msg im getting from this method :-

Error Message

**Phone number verification failed. code: firebaseAuth. Message: this app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed]**

Please have a look,and share your thoughts,may be im doing some mistakes.

```
  // Example code of how to verify phone number
  void _verifyPhoneNumber() async {
    setState(() {
      _message = '';
    });
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
      _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
      setState(() {
        _message = 'Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential';
      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException authException) {
      setState(() {
        _message =
            'Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}';
      });
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      widget._scaffold.showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Please check your phone for the verification code.'),
      ));
      _verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      _verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: _phoneNumberController.text,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }





  // Example code of how to sign in with phone.
  void _signInWithPhoneNumber() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: _verificationId,
      smsCode: _smsController.text,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user =
        (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    setState(() {
      if (user != null) {
        _message = 'Successfully signed in, uid: ' + user.uid;
      } else {
        _message = 'Sign in failed';
      }
    });
  }
```

If u guys need full code please comment it,i'll share full code then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA-1 configuration is not completed at Firebase end,once SHA-1 Configuration is done it will start to run perfectly.

check this link for configuring SHA-1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091158/12072674