# How to fix " Cause: invalid type code: 85" error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, sha1

I got this error when I was trying to get SHA-1 for my flutter application.

[I was watching this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f8YKUulUck)

[StackoverFlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-app)

These solutions are working for everyone but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

pls try to use this cmd:
keytool.exe -list -printcert -jarfile D:\test.apk