# Not able to get SHA-1 key for flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, key, sha1

I am developing a flutter app and want to use google sign in, for that, I require I need my apps SHA-1 keys.

How to get keys is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

But when I run the command `./gradlew signingReport`

I am getting error:-

```
    Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Unable to start the daemon process.
    This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
    For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
    Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
    Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe -Xmx1536M -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp E:\Users\rasku\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.2.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.6.2
    Please read the following process output to find out more:
    -----------------------
    Error occurred during initialization of VM
    Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap


    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I am new to the app signing and google login. What is the problem and how to get the SHA-1 key for the app?

Comment: add SHA-1 key in your firebase account

Comment: how to find the SHA-1 keys?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-app this would definitely work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54342861/12037365 refer this link

Answer (score 2):

To get the debug certificate fingerprint:

for Linux/mac open a terminal and run

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

for windows

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

reference [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

Answer (score 0):

Flow these steps:

1. make sure that you installed Java jdk form this [link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html)
2. add this path to your environment paths
   **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin**
3. restart Android studio
4. run this command in your terminal

   keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users{YOUR USER NAME}.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Answer (score 0):

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 999ms

```
PS D:\flutter\location\firebase_gogl_login\android>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).