# red underline build.gradle in flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I followed the first step in this post [Generate SHA-1 for Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-app)

Now when I open even another project in android studio I have this error.

[build.gradle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqwwm.png)

Answer (score 0):

whenever i got this error i close the build.gradle file and reopen the andriod studio ide , you can try same like this hope it will useful for you

Comment: That does it, but then when I click on build.gradle again the red lines reappear.

Comment: yes, it's alway appear whenever i open the build.gradle file, but i can create my build either it's appear or not.

Answer (score -1):

It doen't mean anything. Simply ignore this error you will be able to create, build and deploy apps as usual

Comment: Actually build failed "Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found."

Comment: try updating your gradle

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, try to close the file and reopen Android Studio. It happened to me as well when I tried to open the build.gradle file on Android Studio. It was behaving well until I tried to open it then I got the red line. But, don’t worry about it it won’t affect your app from running.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to improve the quality of your question.