# Can not use SMS OTP verification in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I created an application to use SMS to verify a phone number with Firebase mobile authentication. But my application always got crashed. I searched for an error but couldn't find anything that makes sense.

Here is my main class that I worked on mobile side:

```
package com.example.otpgenerator4460;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextMobile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextMobile = findViewById(R.id.editTextMobile);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonContinue).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mobilePhone = editTextMobile.getText().toString().trim();

                if(mobilePhone.isEmpty() || mobilePhone.length() < 10){ //5xxxxxxxxx 10 characters
                    editTextMobile.setError("Phone number is not valid");
                    editTextMobile.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VerifyPhoneActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mobile", mobilePhone);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I didn't get any specific error on the screen but I checked logs of my application and couldn't find anything. Here is my log file with errors:

```
2021-01-16 22:19:07.266 3558-3558/? E/tpgenerator446: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-01-16 22:19:07.570 3558-3558/com.example.otpgenerator4460 E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
2021-01-16 22:19:07.576 3558-3594/com.example.otpgenerator4460 E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.otpgenerator4460
2021-01-16 22:19:07.577 3558-3594/com.example.otpgenerator4460 E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-01-16 22:19:07.577 3558-3594/com.example.otpgenerator4460 E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.otpgenerator4460
2021-01-16 22:19:07.577 3558-3594/com.example.otpgenerator4460 E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-01-16 22:19:07.914 3558-3595/com.example.otpgenerator4460 E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory
2021-01-16 22:19:21.773 3558-3558/com.example.otpgenerator4460 E/zzf: Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: 
2021-01-16 22:19:22.570 3558-3558/com.example.otpgenerator4460 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.otpgenerator4460, PID: 3558
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder;
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztw.onPostExecute(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.otpgenerator4460-8ztuJUzUNsGZSw5idMyg2g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.otpgenerator4460-8ztuJUzUNsGZSw5idMyg2g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:230)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:13) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:7) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztw.onPostExecute(Unknown Source:2) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Thanks for any help..

Comment: are you using firebase-bom dependency  read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64588281/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-in-firebase-phone

Comment: after I added dependency I couldn't even build my project in order to test. Here is the error output:

 "Static interface methods are only supported starting with Android N ..."

Comment: I solved that issue with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512629/default-interface-methods-are-only-supported-starting-with-android-n) but now my OTP app redirecting me to firebaseapp web page and finally it says unable to process request due to missing initial state @pankajsharma