# Getting No Activity found to handle Intent while using firebase auth SDK in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase auth for the **phone number, google, Facebook**, and **Apple** in our android app. it's working perfectly in the live version, but sometimes getting crashes in firebase crashlytics as below, and also got few feedback from our customer like they can't be logged in due to this issue.

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://app-id.firebaseapp.com/... flg=0x50000000 (has extras) }
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2067)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5409)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5367)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5753)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5706)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:12)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:7)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztw.onPostExecute(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.4:2)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7943)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:603)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

[image]

Comment: Which line of code produces that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo error logs are the same for all, just the line number is different in Instrumentation.java.

Comment: @AlexMamo do you have any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

**This problem was caused for firebase auth captcha.**
To solve this problem please use the real devices don't use the emulators.

Comment: These all crashes from the live user and its real device, not emulators. @coder

Comment: can you add this one to your project `implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"` and try again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64592432/4238159 
as per that answer might have to resolve in updated firebase_bom, this error is not about to browser, but activity result. even though let me try to add this line. Thanks. @coder