# I cannot find sha1 release key in flutter

Tags: flutter, sha1

hi  I'm trying to find release sha1 key
I followed this Solution
[Generate SHA-1 for Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-app)

and all good but I cannot find
Config : Release sha1 key.

only Debug sha1 key
I only got these

```
Variant: debugUnitTest
Config: debug

Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug

Variant: release
Config: debug

Variant: profile
Config: debug

Variant: releaseUnitTest
Config: debug

Variant: profileUnitTest
Config: debug

Variant: debug
Config: debug
```

all same sha1 key

what is this problem & solution??

Comment: You need to create release config key file first

Comment: you're right thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generate the sh1 with one step:
just run this command

> keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users{Your user name}.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android