# AndroidStudio Can't find the second sha-1 key in signInReport

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter

I need to find 2 keys for my firebase authentication based on
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-app) answer. I found the first one, but I can't find

```
Variant: Release
Config: Release
```

key. It might be because of the warning I get:`Please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.`. However, I have

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in `Project/android/build.gradle` and  `Project/android/app/build.gradle`
How do I fix the warning to get the second sha-1 key?

Here is my tree hierarchy:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the SHA keys at Google Cloud Console after choosing respective project and selecting `API & Services`/`Credentials` from https://console.cloud.google.com/home

Also mentioned line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` should be located within the *build.gradle* file (app module) and not in the project's *build.gradle* file. If you put it in the wrong file, just move the line to the latter.

Comment: In service accounts or API keys?

Comment: And where do I find the build.gradle app module?

Comment: It should be located in your project's tree directories

Comment: u mean "app/build.gradle"? I can't find it

Comment: Yes this is the one you're looking for and in which the line should be located

Comment: I posted the screenshot of my hierarchy, still can't find the app directory

Comment: You can swap the hierarchy view at the top or simply use some folder manager application to look into the project's file hierarchy