# trying to looking for sha1 and sha256 in windows

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, sha1, sha256

excuse me internet, i was trying to get my sha 1 and 256 for firebase authentication project.
i follow the instructions from build.gradle but the gradle wont show the signingreport.

now i trying to do it from gradlew.bat

after i run the gradlew, it show message like this

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in
> your PATH.
>
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
> location of your Java installation.

please, what should i do ?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-react-native-android-native-app

Answer (score 0):

Click on Command Prompt from search  and "Run as administrator"

use
`setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_XX"`

here C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_XX is the folder that has your jdk