# Flutter Firebase not working on release app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, back4app

Flutter Firebase not working when used in release mode while the app is working perfectly fine when in debug mode.
I have added SHA-1 fingerprints but it didn't help.

ps. I have also connected back4app database in the app.

Comment: Do you have any error log related to Firebase while running in release mode?

Comment: @CLucera yes firebase is not responding in the released version

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the error by adding these two lines in the `android/app/build.gradle` :

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SHA-1 is different between release and debug

update

[Generate SHA-1 for Flutter/React-Native/Android-Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-react-native-android-native-app)

Comment: So, what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-react-native-android-native-app