# SHA keys for flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to find the sha key in a github cloned flutter applicaiton.
there is no gradle tab.
and when i am trying to use the gradlew signinReport command in android studio terminal its me giving me the error

gradlew : The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

can anyone tell me where can i find the sha keys ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that it is flutter project , so let me inform you that  gradle operation can not be performed directly from flutter project

you can refer this links to get SHA key

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091158

https://flutteragency.com/how-to-generate-sha-1-in-flutter/

https://medium.com/@MatchaLatt3/finding-sha1-and-sha-256-key-for-flutter-app-in-android-studio-on-windows-e24cc4d76328