# Firebase Google Sign In error 12500 at flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I want to integrate Google Sign In into my app. So I'm useing firebase auth.
Strangely, It works in the emulator but not in the public production version.
Please tell me how to resolve.

This is the error

[image]

I set support email　at　firebase settings and GCP.
I also set SHA-1 and SHA-256.

Comment: Did you put your release SHA1 & 256 in the Firebase console aswell? There are two variants of SHA keys, debug and release. Check accepted answer of this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845559/generate-sha-1-for-flutter-react-native-android-native-app

Comment: I have just done that.
But error still remain.

Answer (score 0):

I have to put SHA1 & 256 from google play in the Firebase console.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).