# Google Sign-In Error with Flutter App in Production Environment

Tags: android, flutter, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We recently transitioned our app's codebase from Kotlin and Swift to Flutter to unify our development process for both Android and iOS platforms. We are building this flutter project as an update to our existing Kotlin project in the Google Play Store.

However, we have encountered a critical issue that is significantly impacting our progress. Our app integrates Google Sign-In for authentication, facilitated by Firebase. We maintain two separate Firebase projects for our development ("dev") and production ("prod") environments.

Issue Description:
In our production environment, specifically for the Android platform, we are experiencing a Google Sign-In error that is preventing users from logging into our app. The error message received is as follows:

PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null))

This issue is particularly perplexing because the same Flutter codebase and SHA-1 fingerprint configurations work seamlessly in our development environment but fail in production. Notably, the same SHA-1 value was previously used in our Kotlin-based project, where it continues to work without any issues in production. This problem does not affect the iOS flutter version of our app, which operates as expected.

Steps Taken to Resolve the Issue:

Updated Flutter and google_sign_in library versions, along with the Gradle version.
Reviewed and updated dependencies within our Gradle configurations.
Double-checked and attempted to update SHA-1 fingerprints in both the Firebase console and Google Play Console. It's worth mentioning that, to verify the correctness of our SHA-1 fingerprints, we tried to re-add the same fingerprint used successfully in our Kotlin project. However, this resulted in an error message indicating that the fingerprint already exists, confirming its presence and accuracy in the configuration.

The exact error we are getting :
E/flutter (12293): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
E/flutter (12293): #0      GoogleSignInApi.signIn (package:google_sign_in_android/src/messages.g.dart:221)
E/flutter (12293): 
E/flutter (12293): #1      GoogleSignInAndroid._signInUserDataFromChannelData (package:google_sign_in_android/google_sign_in_android.dart:111)
E/flutter (12293): 
E/flutter (12293): #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:278)
E/flutter (12293): 
E/flutter (12293): #3      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:431)
E/flutter (12293):

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get your SHA-1 and SHA-256 and add it on your Firebase general project configs.

You can get the SHA keys with gradle. Refer to this [StackOverflow answer that covers it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324221/19265409)

Answer (score 0):

- I think maybe you've missed adding sha **app signing key**
- First, iOS works fine because it doesn't use a signing method like Android, that's why you don't need to add any sha key for iOS config.
- On Android, when you run your project (both debug & release mode) or install your app through APK, using local keystore (also called **upload keystore** - the key you generated by yourself) is fine in this case
- But when you install your app from Google Play (or internal testing or whatever through Google Play), google uses **app signing key** to sign your app (not your upload keystore), so miss adding this sha key will cause the error

-> Solution: find the app signing key on the Play Dashboard like the image attached, and add it to your config

[image]