# How to use the SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having trouble getting my emails to send from my flutter app. I am using google_sign_in.dart but I am getting authentication errors from the signIn() function.

This is the error:

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null))
```

I have read several posts about this error and most of them talk about the SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints you get from Google.

When I look at my Google Console I see 2 sets of hash codes. One is the **Upload Key Certificate** and the other is the App signing key certificate.

How do I use these hash codes? Do I add them both to my Firebase project?

Also, this is my google-services.json. Does it look correct?

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "#########",
    "firebase_url": "https://deal-diligence-5de73-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "deal-diligence-5de5342",
    "storage_bucket": "deal-diligence-5de5342.appspot.com" 
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:###########:android:lskdjroie23roa8dupojr",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.kane.dealdiligence"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "alksjeoirLaosidfJlklkeoiuwei"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

I am working on an Android device.
Thanks.

Comment: Please checkout this answer it helps you :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091158/19807154

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your pc SHA key in your firebase project if you are using the firebase authentication. and if you are not using that not need to add your SHA in it. and you download google-services.json from firebase it was properly working file.If you are using a firebase authentication you can add your SHA at [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2vfv.png) in firebase and also this a doc from Firebase https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth how you can genrate a SHA key

Comment: Thanks for your response but which SHA do I add to my Firebase configuration? I have 2 SHA fingerprints.