This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. please try again, or
enter image description here
if I run my code and connect my device firebase Authentication is work if I take a build  and run my app means this error came
I add correct sha1 and sha 256 upload to firebase
correct google_services.json put
google cloud console enable the play integrity

There might be a configuration issue. if you are giving the release build check the keys sha and sha256 of the release build are added to Firebase.

You've added the SHA1 and SHA256 of your debug app only in firebase. Please add the SHA1 and SHA256 keys of Release to firebase project and it will work just fine.
You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54342861/22623265 if you need reference in getting the keys

very very thank you so much bro
